# Set ObservableCollection as ObservableProperty

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, .net-standard

I'm switching to `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` source generators to handle my view models and I'm a bit confused about how to handle `ObservableCollection`s.

My view model looks like this:

```
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   string name;

   [ObservableProperty]
   ObservableCollection<MyModel> data;

   async Task Init()
   {
      // Fetch data from API
      var response = await _api.GetData();

      if(response.IsSuccessful)
      {
           Name = response.Name;
           Data = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>(response.Data);
      }
   }
}
```

This doesn't seem to assign my data to the `Name` and `Data` properties. I think I'm supposed to assign to `public` properties i.e. `Name` and `Data` and NOT `name` and `data`. Am I right about that?

What am I doing wrong here? Do we use `[ObservableProperty]` with `ObservableCollection` also? I'm missing something here but not sure what.

Comment: I think as with using ObservableCollections usually, you don't want to assign a new instance, that will break the databinding. Instead, create a new instance on the field and clear/add items if new data comes in

Comment: You're right! Thank you. Also, I was missing `this` during my assignment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the answers:

1. As @GeraldVersluis mentioned in the comments, we cannot create a new instance of the `ObservableCollection` during data assignment as it breaks the data binding.
2. We do **NOT** use `[ObservableProperty]` with `ObservableCollection`'s as they automatically call `NotifyPropertyChanged`. Furthermore, quoting Brandon Minnick, `ObservableCollection` should always be a public read-only property, initialized using `= new()`
3. We assign our data to `public` properties
4. We need to use `this` to reference the property
5. Also, notice that I added `new();` to `data` to make sure it's instantiated and is not `null`

Final code looks like this:

```
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   string name;

   ObservableCollection<MyModel> Data { get; } = new();

   async Task Init()
   {
      // Fetch data from API
      var response = await _api.GetData();

      if(response.IsSuccessful)
      {
           this.Name = response.Name;

           foreach(var item in response.Data)
              this.Data.Add(item);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: A very compact yet clear answer!